# Script for removing rows based on entries from specific column in CSV file

Tags: powershell

I have a file structured this way (tab separed):

```
HEADER_1    HEADER_2
entry_A     entry_A
entry_B     entry_C
entry_A     entry_D
entry_D     entry_A
```

What i need to do is: for every time an entry from column one appears in column two (at any point) delete whole row where the entry appears

Desired output:

```
HEADER_1    HEADER_2
entry_B     entry_C
entry_A     entry_D
```

I tried with `Sort-Object -Unique` but the output is not correct, it just removes duplicate lines

Comment: I can see why the 1st row `entry_A     entry_A` is  deleted (column one == column two) however can't understand  it for the 4th line `entry_D     entry_A`…

Comment: I have to agree with @JosefZ. Either the desired output is lines 2-4 eliminating column1==column2 or the desired output is line 2 because column2 never appears in all column1.

Comment: Basically if an entry from column 1 (at any point) appears in column two (at any point) the whole row where the entry appears must go, i'll edit the question to make it clearer

Comment: I feel like what you want to do is output rows where Header_2 has ***not yet appeared*** as a Header_1 value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output the row where Header_2 never contains an entry from all Header_1 values, you can do the following:

**Windows PowerShell:**

```
$data = Import-Csv file.csv -Delimiter "`t"
($data | where Header_1 -notin $data.Header_2 |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoType -Delimiter "`t") -replace '^"|"$|"(\t)"','$1' |
        Set-Content file.csv
```

**PowerShell 7:**

```
$data = Import-Csv file.csv -Delimiter "`t"
$data | where Header_1 -notin $data.Header_2 |
    Export-Csv -NoType -Delimiter "`t" -UseQuotes AsNeeded
```

---

I feel like what you want to do is output rows where Header_2 has not yet appeared as a Header_1 value, which means you are ignoring future Header_1 values.

```
$list = [system.collections.generic.list[string]]@()
(Import-Csv file.csv -delimiter "`t" | Foreach-Object {
    $list.Add($_.Header_1)
    if ($_.Header_2 -notin $list) { 
        $_ 
    }
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType -Delimiter "`t") -replace '^"|"$|"(\t)"','$1' |
        Set-Content file.csv
```

You can go a route without using `*-Csv` commands and then you don't have to deal with qualifying text for PowerShell non-core versions.

```
$list = [system.collections.generic.list[string]]@()
Get-Content file.csv | Foreach-Object {
    $h1,$h2 = $_ -split '\t'
    $list.Add($h1)
    if ($h2 -notin $list) { 
        $_ 
    }
} | Set-Content file.csv
```

Comment: Not sure why but the file remains completely untouched, also if i use export-csv or out-fie at the end of the script it outputs a blank page

Comment: the last solution worked like a charm, and is also really fast, THANKS A LOT

Comment: Strange. When I do Import-Csv file.csv -Delimiter "t",  I get all the contents under one header: `HEADER_1    HEADER_2
--------------------
entry_A     entry_A
entry_B     entry_C
entry_A     entry_D
entry_D     entry_A`.

Comment: @roadrunner You can’t copy and paste their data into a file because the spacing is individual spaces rather than a tab

Comment: @AdminOfThings Ah thought so. Now I remember why I dislike dealing with tab delimited files in the first place :P

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the .NET [`System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) class for O(1) lookups with [`Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1_Contains__0_):

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path file.csv -Delimiter "`t"

$hashSet = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]

$keep = @()
foreach ($row in $data) 
{
    $hashSet.Add($row.HEADER_1)
    if (-not($hashSet.Contains(($row.HEADER_2))))
    {
        $keep += $row
    }
}

$keep | Export-Csv -Path file.csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
```

Which results in a new `file.csv`:

```
"HEADER_1"  "HEADER_2"
"entry_B"   "entry_C"
"entry_A"   "entry_D"
```